# Implementing side-swipe menu like facebook from the parent view which also has different hidden subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, swipe-gesture

I need to create a right side swipe menu in one of the child views like the one in facebook app. I have referred to sample codes like Inferis/ViewDeck.

But my issue is that i want to implement the side swipe on lets say Y view controller. In app delegate, initially X viewcontroller is set. At that time in X viewcontroller, i have set Z viewcontroller as hidden in background. Then when i click on X view's one button, Z viewcontroller is displayed. And from Z viewcontroller I want to perform swipe to open/close to Y viewcontroller.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is the z-index.

You have a view that the user is viewing (View A).  Behind that could be another view that's waiting to be revealed (View B).  Clicking a button on View A, or perhaps swiping across View A, would cause it to animate to the right -- revealing View B waiting below.  Finish your work with View B, then you slide View A back in to place.

This same idea could be used to review multiple levels of views.  View B could slide to reveal View C, and so on.

Comment: No, but the concept of z-index still exists.  A view higher up in the stacking order will cover those below it.

Comment: True, I am just unsure if 'z-index' is the right word in this context.

Comment: z-space?  View hierarchy?  View stacking?  Take your pick.

Comment: @Axeva: Nice suggestion, but i want to control swipe gesture only on View B->C. ViewA->B swipe is not required. Also when I use ViewDeck (https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) sample library, i am unable to perform this feature from View B, since ViewB's parent view would be VIew A, and in ViewDeck i have to assign ViewB as parent(center view) and View C as its right view.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ViewDeck, but this can totally be done in plain-vanilla Cocoa Touch.  View A is the main view in your View Controller.  View B gets added when needed, with View C underneath it.  Then just slide View B to the side when you want to reveal View C.